# Not able to copy files to another Mac in the network via AFP

Tags: afp, file-sharing

I have an iMac and an MBP connected to the same network and I want to transfer files from one machine to the other. I can see the other device listed in my Finder sidebar and connect to it from there. I am able to view the remote files as well. However, when I try to copy files to the remote machine, it doesn't work. When I try to copy, Finder creates a file with the same name but zero bytes in size. It then warns me that a file with the same name exists and do I wish to replace it. On confirming replace, I get the following erorr:

> The operation can’t be completed because an item with the name “” already exists.

I checked the remote machine and see that empty file which just got created remains there with zero bytes size. What could be wrong?

A few more points:

- I have the same user account present on both the machines and I am logging in with that credentials.
- I am the *owner* of the target folder and my account has got write permissions. I have also tried to CHMOD the folder and contents to 777.
- One machine runs Lion and the other Snow Leopard. However, I was getting the same error with two Snow Leopards as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the issue was indeed different UIDs though the usernames were the same.

From the Apple Support Communities link:

> borbye:
>
> The first user that is established on an OSX disc is given UID number
>   501. Normally next user is given UID 502. In my case I could not import my existing user during first run with my new MB Air. Had to
>   establish a testuser and later import my existing user. It turned out
>   that the testuser was giver UID 501 and my existing user was given UID
>   502. Result was the existing users on the two macs are not the same even thoug the username and login is identical..

I tried what was suggested in the support thread and screwed up my entire system - as he had clearly warned.

> borbye:
>
> Check your users in systemprefs -> accounts - open the lock and right
>   click on user -> choose advanced options.
>
> NB: Dont even think you can just change the UID for the user and it
>   will work..... If some more advanced users have a script to change the
>   UID for all files in a home folder, please let us know..

The workaround suggested at the thread didn't quite work for me. But I am not sure if I missed any steps. So you can try this at your own risk.

> one51mac:
>
> borbye is correct that this will remedy the problem but there is a way
>   to do it and have your account work. after changing the user UID and
>   group UID to 501 you will have to restart. then when you log on your
>   home folder will still be your default but you will not have any
>   access. Since you are still an admin you can change that. right click
>   on the home folder and select get info click arrow for sharing and
>   permissions. Your old UID account will show up as _unknown delete this
>   user and add your user to it giving yourself read and write privilege.
>   click on the cog on the bottom and select apply to enclosed items. A
>   warning box will appear stating that this process cannot be undone do
>   you wish to proceed? click yes and a status bar will come up. once the
>   bar is gone the process is complete. since you didn't have access to
>   your home folder you cannot save your settings, this is a good thing
>   since your account will not look remotely the same as yours most
>   likely. all you have to do now is logout and then back in. Your
>   account will look as it did before the change with all the access
>   settings and so forth as before the change... minus some permissions
>   due to the overwrite. It's a minor repair to the permissions to some
>   shares considering you will be able to now move files to and these
>   shares without the permissions alert that only creates a 4kb file
>   instead of the real thing. Takes 5 minutes at most. Have fun.

Ended up doing a fresh install and created a user with the same username as the first one. It took a lot of time to backup and restore all the data but finally I am back on track.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple way..when doing the following:

GO>CONNECT TO SERVER>  (my colleague's iMac)

Stopped my iMac from using stored log in and pw info to connect. Instead I re-typed the credentials to log in to my associate's iMac and it worked. Let me copy large files

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1398462?start=0&tstart=0

I hope it works for you like it did for me. Good luck!

Comment: Can you summarize the procedure rather than just pasting a link?

Comment: I have the same issue and this didn't work for me, the instructions don't really explain what you are supposed to do. For a time I locked myself out of my own MacBook Pro.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Did not solve the problem as such but was able to figure out the reason.